# What do access modifiers at class/object/trait level mean?

Tags: scala

In scala I can add access modifiers to a class/trait/object, like

```
private class Foo
protected[this] trait Foo
```

I have not found any good explanation on these class/trait/object-level modifiers. Do all such combinations make sense and what do they actually mean?

Comment: This is almost certainly a duplicate…

Comment: The semantics for package objects was deferred (with the idea that they might become a module system, to define exports), so the fact that classes in a package belong to an underlying package object isn't spelled out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They mean the same as access modifiers for class/trait members, as classes and traits can also be members of other classes. For example:

```
class A {
    private class Foo
}
```

Class `Foo` is only visible to class `A`. If I change the modifier to `private[this]`, then it is called *object private*, and so any `Foo` is *only* visible to it's parent instance of `A`.

Declaring `private`, `private[this]`, `protected` or `protected[this]` only really makes sense within another class or trait, because it has to be private to *something*. In this case, `Foo` being private to `A`. The same applies to traits.

We could also *not* have a containing object, and make them *package private*.

```
package com.example.foo

private[foo] class Foo
```

Now class `Foo` is only visible to other members of the package `com.example.foo`.

Do they make sense? In some cases I'm sure it is useful to have private classes and traits within some other object.

Comment: Considering package as a container makes sense. When package is the container, does private and private[this] mean the same thing since the container is an object?

Comment: Also, when the container is a package, what does protected modifier mean?

Comment: Just tried. I can compile `private class Foo` or `private[this] class Foo` in a package without problem.

Comment: But try using them elsewhere. They are restricted to themselves, which is not very useful at all.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/som-snytt/e494c792fdbdddb2a4a2 for instance. Nothing mind blowing. Also to answer when protected could be useful as a package member.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't know what I was doing, but it didn't compile in one place, but did in another. Shame on me.

Comment: So I guess that means protected modifier does not make sense under a  package scope since no one can inherit a package. Only private makes sense.